# I have forgotten my scripting ability in Powershell

Tags: powershell

It has been a while since I had to write a PS script and I ran into the wall.  I could use some help...

I need to fix a duplicate SID issue and need to have the script read a list of computers in a text file and perform the actions.  Also, I would like it to create a log file.

```
$rs = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Computers.txt
 
foreach($Computer in $rs) {
   Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer
   {
        Sleep -s 5
        net stop wuauserv
        Sleep -s 5
   Set-Service -Name wuauserv -StartupType Automatic
        reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate /v SusClientId /f
        reg Delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate /v SusClientIDValidation /f
    
    net start wuauserv
        Sleep -s 5
    wuauclt.exe /resetauthorization /detectnow command

 Exit-PSSession 
 }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` is for interactive use, you want `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer { ... }`

Comment: I'd also use Start-Service/Stop-Service vs Net Start/Stop.